# Refused to display iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have 2 pages with urls:

- www.domain.com
- sub.domain.com

I set the "document.domain" for both pages to "domain.com".

```
document.domain = "domain.com"
```

When I try to use  with src "sub.domain.com" in "www.domain.com" I get this error:

```
Refused to display 'https://sub.domain.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means the server is sending out a [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header with a value of `SAMEORIGIN` for your `sub.domain.com` page. This means even if you are setting `document.domain` the parent page has to be on the same origin in order for it to be displayed.

So you need to change how your server sends that header and change it to use `ALLOW-FROM` directive and set the domain you want to allow:

```
ALLOW-FROM https://www.domain.com/
```

Comment: I don't have acces to the subdomain backend

Comment: @ElheniMokhles, Then you are out of luck as there is no way around that as it would be a security issue otherwise